# Insert into table with column same values as auto increment column ( computed column )

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-5.1, identity, computed-column

Say I have a table with "column1" (Primary Key, Auto Increment) and "column2".

How can insert into the table with `column2` will have the same values as `column1` which is auto increment column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table with a **`Calculated column`** that it's value is equal to column1.
Each time you insert a row into your table column1 will be inserted as identity and column2 will be euqal to that.

`MySql :`

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
  (column1 int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  column2 int);
INSERT INTO myTable (name) VALUES('John Doe')
UPDATE mytable SET column2 = column1;
```

Best ways for MySql : Calculated column or trigger that I refer you to these answers : [Calculated Column MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813552/6174449) , [Insert, then update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5222078/6174449), [Create before insert trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7477401/6174449)

You can add other columns like `name`.

`Sql Server :`

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
  (column1 int identity (1,1) NOT NULL,
  name nvarchar(100),
  column2 as column1);

INSERT INTO myTable (name) VALUES('John Doe')
```